# Looking for the Joomla password checking

Tags: joomla, passwords, registration

I search and I can not find the piece of code implemented for checking the password provided by user during registration. That's the code who check if there has the correct number of characters. .. the many figures and many symbols ... etc.

I believe that's this function is implemented since joomla 3.0, my version is joomla 3.2

I would like to "copy" this code for one of my joomla personal scripts.

I searched the in the controllers and models of "com_users", and in plugin "users" without success.

I also studied the bind() methode and save() methode of class JUser but I found nothing.

Does anyone know where this code? I would be saving valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

It is in a `jform` : `components/com_users/models/forms/registration.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
    <fieldset name="default"
        label="COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_DEFAULT_LABEL"
    >
            <!-- STUFF HERE -->    

        <field name="password2" type="password"
            autocomplete="off"
            class="validate-password"
            description="COM_USERS_DESIRED_PASSWORD"
            field="password1"
            filter="raw"
            label="COM_USERS_PROFILE_PASSWORD1_LABEL"
            message="COM_USERS_PROFILE_PASSWORD1_MESSAGE"
            size="30"
            validate="equals"
            required="true"
        />

        <field name="password1" type="password"
            autocomplete="off"
            class="validate-password"
            description="COM_USERS_PROFILE_PASSWORD2_DESC"
            filter="raw"
            label="COM_USERS_PROFILE_PASSWORD2_LABEL"
            size="30"
            validate="password"
            required="true"
        />

            <!-- OTHER STUFF THERE -->

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And in `libraries` folder : `libraries/joomla/form/fields/password.php`

```
/**
     * Method to attach a JForm object to the field.
     *
     * @param   SimpleXMLElement  $element  The SimpleXMLElement object representing the <field /> tag for the form field object.
     * @param   mixed             $value    The form field value to validate.
     * @param   string            $group    The field name group control value. This acts as as an array container for the field.
     *                                      For example if the field has name="foo" and the group value is set to "bar" then the
     *                                      full field name would end up being "bar[foo]".
     *
     * @return  boolean  True on success.
     *
     * @see     JFormField::setup()
     * @since   3.2
     */
    public function setup(SimpleXMLElement $element, $value, $group = null)
    {
        $return = parent::setup($element, $value, $group);

        if ($return)
        {
            $this->maxLength = $this->element['maxlength'] ? (int) $this->element['maxlength'] : 99;
            $this->threshold = $this->element['threshold'] ? (int) $this->element['threshold'] : 66;

            $meter       = (string) $this->element['strengthmeter'];
            $this->meter = ($meter == 'true' || $meter == 'on' || $meter == '1');
        }

        return $return;
    }

    /**
     * Method to get the field input markup for password.
     *
     * @return  string  The field input markup.
     *
     * @since   11.1
     */
    protected function getInput()
    {
        // Translate placeholder text
        $hint = $this->translateHint ? JText::_($this->hint) : $this->hint;

        // Initialize some field attributes.
        $size         = !empty($this->size) ? ' size="' . $this->size . '"' : '';
        $maxLength    = !empty($this->maxLength) ? ' maxlength="' . $this->maxLength . '"' : '';
        $class        = !empty($this->class) ? ' class="' . $this->class . '"' : '';
        $readonly     = $this->readonly ? ' readonly' : '';
        $disabled     = $this->disabled ? ' disabled' : '';
        $required     = $this->required ? ' required aria-required="true"' : '';
        $hint         = $hint ? ' placeholder="' . $hint . '"' : '';
        $autocomplete = !$this->autocomplete ? ' autocomplete="off"' : '';
        $autofocus    = $this->autofocus ? ' autofocus' : '';

        if ($this->meter)
        {
            JHtml::_('script', 'system/passwordstrength.js', true, true);
            $script = 'new Form.PasswordStrength("' . $this->id . '",
                {
                    threshold: ' . $this->threshold . ',
                    onUpdate: function(element, strength, threshold) {
                        element.set("data-passwordstrength", strength);
                    }
                }
            );';

            // Load script on document load.
            JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration(
                "jQuery(document).ready(function(){" . $script . "});"
            );
        }

        // Including fallback code for HTML5 non supported browsers.
        JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
        JHtml::_('script', 'system/html5fallback.js', false, true);

        return '<input type="password" name="' . $this->name . '" id="' . $this->id . '"' .
            ' value="' . htmlspecialchars($this->value, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '"' . $hint . $autocomplete .
            $class . $readonly . $disabled . $size . $maxLength . $required . $autofocus . ' />';
    }
```

I think it is what you want.

If you're lost with Joomla Jforms, then use [jquery validation plugin](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation). Its [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/).

Answer (score 0):

You can create plugin that check if password is valid and return true is yes;

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die ;

class plgUserHookbizz extends JPlugin {

 function onUserBeforeSave($user,$options)
 {
       $app = JFactory::getApplication();
       // Joomla session parameters
       $userId   = $user['id'];
       $name     = $user['name'];
       $password     = $user['password'];
       $username = $user['username'];
       $email    = $user['email'];


       if($this->validate($password)){
        return true;
       }else{
        $app->enqueueMessage('Please enter a valid password');
        return false;
       }
 }

 function validate($password){
   //Your validation here
   //Return true if valid
   return true;

 }
```

}